# is there a reason podman wont let me chown?

Tags: podman

the namespace situation with podman is a bit confusing to me.

below i'm trying to change the namespace to match the groupid i have setup for dba(5430) and userid for avnav(1000)

this came about because mounting a volume with a postgres container isn't working.  but i cant even change these directories manually, it seems.

**ls -la /home/_volumes/**

```
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 100999  105429 4096 Sep  8 20:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 avnav   avnav   4096 Aug 20 01:48 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 avnav   dba    4096 Sep  9 00:55 pg_db1
```

looks good...

**podman unshare ls -la /home/_volumes/**

```
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 avnav  dba     4096 Sep  8 20:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 root   root    4096 Aug 20 01:48 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   nogroup 4096 Sep  9 00:55 pg_db1
```

ok... need to change this...

**podman unshare chown -R avnav:dba /home/_volumes/**

**podman unshare chown -R 1000:5430 /home/_volumes/**

```
chown: changing ownership of '/home/_volumes/pg_db1': Operation not permitted
```

not sure what the problem is here. and obviously, i cant do this with root.

even tried:

**podman unshare chown 100999:105429 /home/_volumes/pg_db1 -R**

and i get:

```
changing ownership of '/home/_volumes/pg_db1': Invalid argument
```

Comment: something weird...i was able to do this:

podman unshare chown root:root /home/_volumes/pg_db1 -R

Comment: turns out when i do that, it undoes the regular ls -la ...turning it to root and nogroup again

Answer (score 2):

ok, i'm not very clear on why i was unable to unshare with podman.

however, using crun, i was able to get my postgres container to actual mount volumes and read older data.

i did this first by installing the dependencies outlined in the git repo:
https:// github.com/containers/crun
which consist of the following for ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y make git gcc build-essential pkgconf libtool \
   libsystemd-dev libcap-dev libseccomp-dev libyajl-dev \
   go-md2man libtool autoconf python3 automake
```

then, i put added the following line:

```
--annotation run.oci.keep_original_groups=1 --userns=keep-id \
```

taken from:
https:// [www.redhat.com/sysadmin/supplemental-groups-podman-containers](http://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/supplemental-groups-podman-containers)

basically, this allows you to attach your user's groups to the container as well.

again, not sure why i cant unshare, and set the container users to something arbitrary like with:

```
--user 5430
```

final:

```
podman run \
--annotation run.oci.keep_original_groups=1 --userns=keep-id \ (instead of --user 5430)
--name pg_db1 \
--pod abd1 \  (used this instead of -p 5432:5432 since it's in a pod.)
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 \
-e POSTGRES_USER=db1 \
-e POSTGRES_DB=dbb \
-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
-v '/home/_volumes/pg_db1/':'/var/lib/postgresql/data' \
postgres:13.3-alpine
```

hope this helps someone...i broke my head on this for a while.